# Symfony2 Form Generation from Vendor Classes

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-forms

Working with Symfony2 and trying to figure out how best to incorporate Vendor libraries. Calling vendor library methods is very easy using the routing configs: `use` the appropriate `namespace`, generate the class name, the method to call, and the arguments from a couple path components and query vars, voila, instant integration.

I'm having trouble with forms, though. My goal seems like it should be very easy. I want to make forms in Symfony2 from vendor classes. As a specific example, consider the [google-api-php-client](https://github.com/evert/google-api-php-client). It seems like `->createForm()` would work best, because it bridges to the ORM and validation so nicely. However, it relies on a a `MyBundle\Form\ThingType` file and class. To create this class, I need an entity within my bundle. I can't (or haven't been able to figure out how to) just use existing "Entities" from vendor libraries. Creating the "Entity" in the Symfony nomenclature when a "Model" already exists in the API lingo seems to be inflexible and very un-D.R.Y.

The other method I've gotten to work is using

`$formBuilder = $this->createFormBuilder(new GoogleApi\Contrib\Event);`

then

`foreach(get_object_vars($event) as $prop) { $formBuilder->add($prop); }`

but this does not utilize the seemingly ready-made bridge between the API documentation and the built-in validation tools, and it also means each individual data type is going to have to be declared individual or array to decide whether to include a collection of class-based forms or a single, class-based form.

In short, I want to use the properties and dataType information available in the API, and, if necessary, [the Resource representations like this one](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events) to create a simple function (like my call function) for creating nested, self-validating forms for the classes in the Google API. I want to accomplish this without creating a bunch of "Entities" and "FormTypes" that simply rewrite what is already written in the library.

Answer (score 1):

Did the vendor library not have any installation details? You should generally calls vendor things from the controller using service calls like `$this->get('vendor.name.form_object')` rather than calling the class at the service will include any needed dependencies.

Also the entity that you would create in your bundle would only be the basic entity that would then extend their premade abstract classes. For example (taken from https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle)

```
<?php
// src/Acme/UserBundle/Entity/User.php

namespace Acme\UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }
}
```

If you want to add any of your own entity items then you can do it in this, but still keep the methods and properties from the base entity/model.

Comment: There are no form objects, as the library was not specifically designed for Symfony, but as a general PHP tool. The classes are not all in independent files, and they do not follow Symfony naming conventions, which is why I'm having trouble.

Comment: These aren't abstract classes, though, and I don't want to insert any of my own logic. Actually, that's precisely the problem. I guess how I'd describe it is I'm trying to "translate" the naming conventions from the API library to Symfony. I want to use all of the aspects of the ORM **except** database persistence.

Comment: Then I can't help I'm afraid.

Comment: I appreciate the contribution regardless. I now have a better idea about the purpose of foundational bundles like FOSUser. Cheers.